# Unable to access “136 GB Volume”

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, usb-drive, drive

This error message is shown every time I try to access the flash drive.

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/hp/868E-F233: Command-line`mount -t "exfat" -o 
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,
errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/hp/868E-F233"' exited with 
non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

Pls help me out! Thankyou in advance...

Comment: Have you installed the `exfat-utils` for your system to read `exfat` partitions?  `sudo apt-get install exfat-utils`

Answer (score 1):

It seems your drive is formated to exFAT. Ubuntu doesn't come with support for that upon installation. You need to install `exfat-utils` and `exfat-fuse`.

Do this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error message:


Unable to access “136 GB Volume”
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/hp/868E-F233: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/hp/868E-F233"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:
stdout: `FUSE exfat 1.0.1
'
stderr: `ERROR: unknown entry type 0x80.

Comment: @RatnajothySangeethanan This guy: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exfat/IMN5xlhC_X0 seems to have the same issue with you. Can you mound your exFAT drive in Windows? Does Windows recognize it as exFAT, too?

Comment: In Win 10 I Get This Error When Opening The Drive:

The location is not available
F:\ is not accessible.
The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

Comment: @RatnajothySangeethanan So this is no longer a Ubuntu problem this way...

Comment: @RatnajothySangeethanan I am not sure if this can be fixed. Was it like this before you ever try to mount it in Ubuntu? If your file system is corrupted maybe you should format it. If it keeps going this way it means the drive has hardware damage...